# vue.js: check if css class is binded in template

Tags: javascript, css, web, vue.js

I am learning Vue.js hence new to it. I am having difficulty to check whether my class is bonded dynamically. I am trying to add effect: when I hover over a card it should go up a little bit and change its color. Besides, not just css but also custom events are also not working.

Here is my card component:

```
Vue.component('card', {

    props: ['def'],

    template: `
        <div class="card" :class="'type-' + def.type" @click="play">

            <div class="title">{{ def.title }}</div>
            <img class="separator" src="svg/card-separator.svg" />

            <div class="description">
                <div v-html="def.description"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="note" v-if="def.note">
                <div v-html="def.note"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    `,

    methods: {
        play() {
            this.$emit('play')
            this.$emit('test_event_with_args', 'str_arg', 777)
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        this.$on("play", ()=> {
            console.log("custom event play ni tutdim ready hook ni ichida")
        })

        this.$on('test_event_with_args', (str, num) => {
            console.log(`Test_Event: str=${str}, num=${num}`);
        })
    }

});
```

Here is an excerpt from my css file:

```
.card:hover{
    top: -5px
}

.card.type-attack{
    background:#9b1b1b
}
.card.type-special{
    background:#751b9b
}
.card.type-support{
    background:#1b6e9b
}
```

Comment: You need to add the position attribute, like this  `.card:hover {
    top: -5px;
    position: relative;
}`

Comment: Your events are working, why do you say they aren't?

Comment: maybe there is something wrong in other parts of my code, that is why in my browser events are not working and css are not bonded, let me check again then

Comment: Your CSS is missing semi-colons

Comment: @Phil not really an error unless there were more attributes

Comment: I think your class should be this `:class="{['type-' + def.type]: true)}"`

Comment: @A.Lau given OP said it's an _"excerpt"_, I thought maybe they didn't have **any** semi-colons and that may be why it appears the class isn't applying

Comment: So, were they working, after all?